# Linux script to write data from telnet message into a file while a period

Tags: linux, bash, telnet

I am connecting to a telnet listener. Telnet server sends some data for every second. I want to read the messages while X seconds and write it into a file (we'll take 6 seconds for the example).

Note: The IP address has been changed to 'IP' for the example. Same for 'Port'.

I already tried some things:

```
#!/bin/bash
#myScript.sh

telnet IP Port >> myFile.txt
sleep 6
pkill myScript.sh
```

This solution write in my file but my script never ends.

Here my 2nd proposition:

```
#!/bin/bash
#myScript.sh

timeout 6 telnet IP Port >> myFile.txt
```

Here, it's another issue, timeout is respected, the script ends after 6 seconds but in 'myFile.txt', I have

```
Trying IP...
Connected to IP.
Escape character is '^]'
```

How can I make this script right?

Note: I must use Telnet.

Comment: That's normal telnet output. netcat is a more appropriate choice for non-interactive use in a script...

Comment: Switch to `netcat`, `nc` or `socat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your first solution you could try try:

   ```
   telnet IP Port 2>&1 | tee myFile.txt &
   sleep 6
   exit
   ```

This will send the telnet command to a background process and then exit after 6 seconds.

2. In your second solution you could try:

   ```
   timeout 6 telnet IP Port 2>&1 | tee myFile.txt
   ```

This sends stderr and stdoutt to myFile.txt

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Streams.html

3. Or, as others have suggested, use netcat:

   ```
   timeout 6 nc -vz IP Port 2>&1 | tee myFile.txt
   ```

http://netcat.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It's works in the console but in my script it's the same issue, only the 3 lignes are printed in the file. I tried netcat and it's works

Comment: The first solution doesn't work but the second is better: the file contains the data but after 6 seconds, the script restarts again and again, it's strange. Netcat works for me, thanks.